# Enabling Listener on bukkit

Tags: java, bukkit

```
package me.TimewalkerZ.Broadcastoncommand;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginDescriptionFile;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.*;

public class Broadcastoncommand extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {
   public final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Minecraft");
   public static Broadcastoncommand plugin;

   @Override
   public void onDisable() {
           PluginDescriptionFile pdfFile = this.getDescription();
           this.logger.info(pdfFile.getName() +  " Has been Disabled!");
    }

   @Override
   public void onEnable() {
           PluginDescriptionFile pdfFile = this.getDescription();
           this.logger.info(pdfFile.getName() + " Version " + pdfFile.getVersion() +  " Has been Enabled!");
           getConfig().options().copyDefaults(true);
           saveConfig();
   }

   @EventHandler
   public void onPlayerCommandPreprocessEvent(PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent event) {
       Player p = event.getPlayer();
       if(!p.hasPermission("Broadcastoncommand.silent")) {
           List<String> cmds = plugin.getConfig().getStringList("CommandsBC");
           for (String command : cmds) {
               if(event.getMessage().toLowerCase().startsWith("/" + command)) {
               p.sendMessage("§6" + p + "§6 just did the command " + command + "§6 join them if you have the command unlocked.");
             }
           }
         }
       }
```

Hi, I tried running this but it doesn't seem to work at all. I mean that it compiles and runs without error but it doesn't do anything in game. The purpose of this plugin, by the way, is to broadcast whenever somebody uses a command in the config.

Comment: what did you _try_ and what is your _question_?

Answer (score 3):

Add this line in your `onEnable` method:

```
getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
```

The first `this` parameter is the plugin of which to register events for, and the second `this` parameter is the plugin's listeners.

---

Along with this, a NullPointerException is being thrown because of "plugin". This is returning null because `plugin` isn't set to anything. Instead, use this

```
List<String> cmds = this.getConfig().getStringList("CommandsBC");
```

Another way to achieve this but keeping the singleton pattern would be to assign the plugin instance to `plugin` on start up, by adding this line in `onEnable`:

```
plugin = this;
```

Answer (score 0):

To register your events you will need to add:

```
Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
```

to register `this` listener to `this` class

---

You are also getting a `NullPointerException` because of either:

- 1.) `plugin` is null, ultimately you can remove the `plugin.` because it is your main class and `getConfig()` is a method in the parent class.
- 2.) `getConfig()` is returning null because the fil does not exist or is not generated. You need to add `config.yml` to your `src` folder in your project, after this you will need to generate it when your plugin enables by using the `saveDefaultConfig()` method *if* the file does not exist. e.g.:

  ```
  try 
  {
      File config  = new File(getDataFolder(), "config.yml");
      if(!getDataFolder().exists())getDataFolder().mkdirs();
      if(!config.exists())saveDefaultConfig();
  } 
  catch (Exception e) 
  {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  ```
- 3.) The specified path in config does not exist. Remember paths are case sensitive. `getConfig().getStringList("CommandsBC")` could be returning null due to an empty list, or the path does not exist (remember it is case-sensitive).

  Theses options could result in your `NullPointerException`, if you need more information leave a comment.